# Replace or extend a URL in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I changed the position of some files in my file server and I need the update the URL of the file in my database.

For example from:

```
/sba/sbazen/test/SBA33G_TC/3300009//00150671.pdf
```

I want to get:

```
/sba/sbazen/test/SBA33G_TC/new_folder_name/3300009//00150671.pdf
```

Important to know: The number on SBA33G is variable. We can have SBA100G or SBA02G.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain further what you want help with?

Answer (score 0):

if the old folder path is always the same length you can use [stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select len('/sba/sbazen/test/SBA33G_TC/'), stuff(t.oldval, 27, 1, '/new_folder_name/')
from (
    select '/sba/sbazen/test/SBA33G_TC/3300009//00150671.pdf' oldval 
) t
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But in in my path just the number after SBA is variable. i could be SBA32G or SBA100G.

Comment: So how do you know which one to use for replacement? Put that login in the select part with a `case`.

Comment: @Arthurofos, You need to clarify exactly the specifications in your **question**

Comment: @kobik sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use [Update](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)?

```
UPDATE tableName
SET
   colName = '/sba/sbazen/test/SBA33G_TC/new_folder_name/3300009//00150671.pdf'
WHERE colName = '/sba/sbazen/test/SBA33G_TC/3300009//00150671.pdf'
```